# How to get the data from Firebase to create a list?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, httpclient

My goal is to create a portfolio page where the user can add arworks by filling a form (titel, technique, image, yaer etc.). Submited data will be added to an array and presented in a form of a list.

I'm able to upload the array to the firebase but I don't know how to upload it when the site starts. I want it to update and refresh the list on the page each time I submit an item. I spent hours looking for the right way to do it.

```
//SERVER.SERVICE

export class ServerService {
  url:string = 'https://basic-31cd5.firebaseio.com';

constructor(
  private httpClient: HttpClient,
  private artService:ArtService
  ) { }

  storeArtworks() {
    return this.httpClient.put( this.url +"/artworks.json", 
    this.artService.getArtworks());
  }

  getArtworks() {
    return this.httpClient.get<HttpResponse<Art[]>> 
  (this.url+"/artworks.json")};
  }

//ART.SERVIVCE

import { Art } from "../modules/art.module"
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

export class ArtService{
    listChanged = new Subject<Art[]>();

    public list: Art[] = [];
        // new Art ("The Young Ladies of Avignon", "painting", 1907),
        // new Art ("Kiss", "painting", 1908),
        // new Art ("Dance", "painting", 1911)

    subject = new Subject<string>();



    setArt(artworks:Art[]=[]){
        this.list = artworks;
        this.listChanged.next(this.list);
    }

    getArtworks() {
        return this.list;
    }

    addArt(f){
        this.list.push( new Art( f.value.titel, f.value.technique, f.value.year));
    }

    remove(titel){
    // this.list.splice(i, 1)
        for (let i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
          if( this.list[i].titel === titel )
          { this.list.splice( i,1 ) }
        }
  }
}

//DashboardComponent

  list;

  constructor(
    private serverService:ServerService, private artService:ArtService ) 
    {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.list = this.artService.getArtworks();
  }

  submit(form:NgForm){
    this.artService.addArt(form);
  }

  removeItem(titel){
    this.artService.remove(titel)
  }
  onSave(){
    this.serverService.storeArtworks()
      .subscribe( (res:Response) => console.log(res));
  }
}
```

Comment: I went through some of your questions, it seems like you don't accept answer. People take their time to answer your questions, so if the provided answer, answers your question accept their answer by clicking the right arrow next to their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
getList() {
        let listDB = this.db.database.ref('/tasks').child(this.uid);
        listDB.on('value', (snapshot) => {
            const items = snapshot.val();
            if(items) {
                this.list = Object.keys(items).map(i => items[i]);
                console.log('this.list', this.list)`enter code here`;
            }
        })
    }
```